# Class already registered as subclass

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I bought a plugin, it worked fine when I first activated it, but when I try to close it and open it again, I get this error Please help

Error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 371, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\Feroa\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\Delete_Static_Channels\__init__.py", line 34, in register
    preferences.register()
  File "C:\Users\Feroa\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\Delete_Static_Channels\preferences.py", line 57, in register
    register_class(DELETESTATICCHANNELS_preferences)
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass 'DELETESTATICCHANNELS_preferences'
```

Comment: Since it's a third-party addon and not built into Blender you'll have to ask the addon author about that one!

Comment: The author cannot be reached, how can I solve this?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. Are you sure that the version you have is compatible with the Blender version that you are using? Is there a web page for that addon anywhere that we can see?

Comment: yes, the plugin is compatible, it was working when I first activated it, but when I try to close and open it again, the plugin gives an error. 

addon https://gofile.io/d/L4xIPO

Comment: Try here: https://blastframe.com/contact/

Comment: If I'm going to write there, why would I seek help here? you are seriously helping me this way there is no need wow thank you for your help

Comment: The link to that web site was in the source code of the addon (__init__.py) which is usually the first place to look for information.

Answer (score 1):

That sharing site won't let me download the addon, so I can't look at the source code directly, but I think you should be able to solve this yourself with a bit of guidance.

Go to this location on your computer:

`C:\Users\Feroa\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\Delete_Static_Channels\preferences.py`

and open it in a code editor of some kind. Go to line 57, where it says the error is occurring.

it should say:

`register_class(DELETESTATICCHANNELS_preferences)`

replace that with:

```
try:
    register_class(DELETESTATICCHANNELS_preferences)
except ValueError:
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DELETESTATICCHANNELS_preferences)
    register_class(DELETESTATICCHANNELS_preferences)
```

The error is coming from blender trying to register a class and finding that it has already been registered. This fix just says "Try to register it, if for some reason it doesn't work; move on."

This is probably not a super-legit solution but it might just make the addon work until you can get in contact with the developer (Which, like others have suggested, should be your ultimate goal.)

Comment: It let me download it without problem which is how I found the web address in the init file! Unfortunately I haven't used python for many years so didn't investigate any further.

Comment: it didn't work ;/

Comment: it didn't work ;/
https://hastebin.com/jipeqekebi.py   (init.py)
https://hastebin.com/ugemimaboy.sql (preferences.py)
https://hastebin.com/okiwadekay.py  (operators.py)
https://hastebin.com/ixajuzaxih.lua (util.py)

Comment: I editied my answer, see if this version works now.

Comment: It didn't work. I gave the direct link of the code. I uploaded the code here from a well known site "Hastebin". Links are not bad

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 335, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Feroa\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\Yeni klasör\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import preferences
  File "C:\Users\Feroa\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\Yeni klasör\preferences.py", line 58
    try:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: https://hastebin.com/jipeqekebi.py (init.py)   
 https://hastebin.com/ugemimaboy.sql (preferences.py)  
 https://hastebin.com/okiwadekay.py (operators.py)  
 https://hastebin.com/ixajuzaxih.lua (util.py)

Comment: This error comes from not indenting properly, probably comes from an issue with the formatting from copying it out of the browser. make sure the indentation looks like it did before, and my code matches the formatting in the browser.